# Can I enter Malaysia, as a Libyan without a visa?

Tags: visas, malaysia, libyan-citizens

I have roundtrip way ticket arrive at 15 March 2014 and depart at 28 March 2014, I will attend the TAEEAC 2014 conference, I have registered. As I am Libyan citizen, can I get a visa at the Airport?

My passport Valid until 28 Aug. 2014.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Malaysian immigration department](http://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/main-services/visa/visa-requirement-by-country/7-perkhidmatan-utama/286-visa-requirement-by-country) as a Libyan you don't need a visa if your stay does not exceed 14 days.

Given that you stay is exactly that much you shouldn't have to apply for a visa.  If you intend to stay longer then you will need a visa and likely from the consulate in your home country.